# Clarfication regarding the IF - Else ladder

Tags: python, if-statement

I have written a function in which i have used a if else ladder and i have written it in two versions and in the first version there is no error but in the second version i am facing an error although both versions are performing the same tasks(It is done in python)

**VERSION ONE OF THE CODE(NO ERROR)**

```
def caught_speeding(speed,is_birthday):
if(speed>60 and speed<=80):
    if(is_birthday==True and speed<=65):
        print('no ticket')
    else:
        print('small ticket')
elif(speed>80):
    if(is_birthday==True and speed<=85):
        print('no ticket')
    else:
        print('big ticket')
else:
    print('no ticket')
```

**VERSION TWO OF THE CODE(ERROR)**

```
def caught_speeding(speed,is_birthday):
if(speed>60 and speed<=80):
    if(is_birthday==True and speed<=65):
        print('no ticket')
    else:
        print('small ticket')
else:
    if(speed>80):
        if(is_birthday==True and speed<=85):
            print('no ticket')
        else:
            print('big ticket')
else:
    print('no ticket')
```

The error that gets printed upon executing of versoin two of the code is:

```
File "<ipython-input-45-0ed6a5391a7f>", line 13
else:
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I need clarifiaction on the "elif" part

Comment: You can't have two elses on one if - what m exactly should the _second_ one match?

Comment: What the last `else` part is doing there? the last `else` part should be inside the outer `else` block against the condition `if(speed>80)`

Answer (score 0):

There's an issue with your logic. `if` statements in python can stand alone, be extended with an `elif`, or ended with an `else`. You already end the
`if(speed>60 and speed<=80):` in line 2 with the `else` in line 7.

```
        print('small ticket')
else: <-----------------------------
    if(speed>80):
```

The logic is also different, since the first code snippet has a condition for `speed > 80` and the `else` covers `speed <= 60`. The second code snippet the `else` covers both `speed > 80` or `speed <= 60`, so the second `else` doesn't mean anything and is just a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

If is the "main" condition statement, but elif gives you chance to catch another condition along with the main one.
Else catches everything that's not stated by if or elif statement, so you cannot catch else twice. First else statement will cover all situations that will not meet if statement conditions, so having another one is illogical -> causing Syntax Error.